# Plot a heatmap using two columns of a pandas dataframe as two parameters

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap

I have a pandas dataframe which has around 2000 rows and it looks like this:

```
    qba_alias_prob   y_score
0             0.3016  0.391449
1             0.8735  0.463365
2             0.5530  0.405257
3             0.5984  0.706649
4             0.7980  0.636735
...              ...       ...
1736          0.9902  0.749777
1737          0.4439  0.704889
1738          0.9694  0.814441
1739          0.9694  0.988001
1740          0.9358  0.781842
```

There are two columns which contains a probability score between 0 to 1. Now i want to plot a heatmap between these two columns ( any of the two columns can be on any axis ).I saw several solutions for doing this but they are plotting the heatmap between the index value and column value of a dataframe but not between two columns.

I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df= pd.read_csv('/Users/meenumee/Downloads/heatmap_toys.csv')

sns.heatmap(df, annot=True)
```

I got this output.

[image]

But i want the heatmap to be as qba_alias_prob on one axis lets say X axis and y_score to be on Y axis. And also i want a bigger heatmap where i can get more cleaner view of the data.

As enke suggested

```
sns.heatmap(df.set_index('qba_alias_prob'), annot=True)
```

I am getting this:
[image]

But  how can i make this a little visualisable? On the Y axis, the probability are in random order. Also this is very messy.

Comment: You have defined what you want as X and Y, but what do you want as Z/color ?

Comment: Use [histogram2d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) to get the density/heatmap, then you can plot it with `sns.heatmap` or `plt.imshow`.

Comment: @Guimoute there is no such priority but the colors should be able to give good view of the distribution.

Comment: @enke yeah. I mean I am not able to get some visualisation from this also? though it did put them in two different axis.

Comment: Are you sure the probabilities are numeric? Why aren't they sorted when you plot?

Comment: @enke yes they are numeric.

Comment: What do you expect to achieve by annotating 2000 unique lines in a graph? I assume what you want is what Quang Hoang suggested.

Comment: Hey @Mr.T i want to see if there are some patterns in the data.

Comment: This is what Quang Hoang suggested - bin data to see in which bins more values are accumulated. So far, you just have colored your pandas dataframe.